# Defrag tool for Windows that will move all files to beginning of the partition?

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, file-management, defragmentation

Sometimes Windows partitions wind up with movable files/folders at the end of the partition, even when the partition is mostly empty.  This makes it impossible to shrink the partition using Windows' Disk Management tool.

Is there a Windows 7 compatible gratis defragmentation tool that will move all files/folders to the beginning of the partition?

I tried the well-regarded [UltraDefrag](http://ultradefrag.sourceforge.net/) as well as the integrated Windows defragmentation tool.  Both left many movable files at the end of the partition.

Note that I am *not* referring to moving swap files or hibernation files.

Comment: Have you asked on SuperUser what files could be blocking the defrag process?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Interestingly, nothing is blocking the defrag.  The files are defragmented, just not consolidated.

Comment: This is comment because it does not run inside windows.  gparted and/or parted magic offer a way to boot into a linux desktop.  gparted can then shrink/resize any partition without the need to manually move files out of the way.  Obviously if the file is not protected, you could just cut the file,and move it to another drive temporarily.

Comment: `This makes it impossible to shrink the partition using Windows' Disk Management tool`  - which I stopped using long ago, in favour of the excellent, and free, https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html which can shrink such a partition, no problem. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Mawg Thanks.  It's been on my list of tools to try, but I have not tried it yet.  I don't see a portable version on their site.  Do you know if they offer one?

Comment: I prefer it, because it can generally resize a partition without reboot, so long as the partition is not in use (plus a ton of other features). Please, do give it a try. As to a portable versions, I would try portable apps, but can’t as I am behind a company firewall. Even if you can’t find one, there are apps to convert programs to portable version, by adding a wrapper which intercepts registry calls & writes to a local .ini instead. Btw, you didn’t mention portable in your question ;-)

Comment: Minitool partition magic. Just resize the partition.